# How variable reassignment with different type of value works in Python memory?

Tags: python

Suppose I have declared a variable in Python:
a = 1
and in next line I changed it to -
a = "Hello"
so in this case what exactly happened in memory?
does Python create a new memory location/object to store a = "Hello" or it simply overwrite the value from "a=1" to a = "Hello" at same memory location.

Comment: read [this](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: From my understanding, `a` is just an alias in python, and does not affect memory. That is when you say `a=1`, 1 is assigned to memory, and `a` is just a means to access it. If you have another variable `b=1`, both will access the same 1 in memory. So `a='Hello'` will create `Hello` in memory, and assign a to it. Now, if no other variable in workspace has 1 as a value, garbage collection will take care of it and free that memory.

Comment: You can try id(a) at various points of life of variable to find out where a is pointing at

Comment: @GergesDib it is a special case that `1` happens to be a singleton object, but that is only the case for small integers in CPython, and that is an implementation detail. Normally, even for immutable data structures like `tuple`, a new object is created with literal notation, so `a, b = (), ()` creates two separate objects.

Comment: A python variable is a name that refers to an object. It has no association with a memory location, unlike `C` for example.

Comment: @GergesDib Thank a lot for your input and providing detailed information.

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak - The use of id() function clears the whole picture for me, thanks a lot for the suggestion, don't know why it didn't came to my mind. :)

Comment: `id()` is often overlooked, but is handy in tracing in cases like when you do not really understand which variable is affected or should one to make a copy of the variable to get desired output.